# R function to convert rows where all binary values are 0 into NA, for a set of multiple columns

Tags: r, binary

I have a dataset with several binary values. I'd like to convert 0s to NA in rows that add up to 0 .

How would I go about doing this?

Example:

```
RespondentID   Popn1 Popn2 Popn3  ...... Popn20             Funding1   Funding2 Funding3
     1           1     0    0               0                  1           0       1
     2           0     0    0     ......    0                  0           0       1
     3           1     1    0    .......    1                  0           0       0
```

I'd like to find and convert rows with all 0s for specific columns to NA. For example, I'd like to convert Row 2 (where respondentID is 2) to NA for Popn1:Popn20, as they add up to 0 (assuming that the variables I haven't shown there are all 0 for that row as well). I'd also like to turn row 3 for columns Funding1:Funding3 to NA/Blank as they add up to 0 (ie all values are 0.

Is there a way to do this, and for a number of such columns? (100+). There are sets of such variables, so I'd be selective about which columns to be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with direct assignment:

```
cols = grepl("Popn", names(df1))
df1[rowSums(df1[cols]) == 0, cols] = NA

cols = grepl("Funding", names(df1))
df1[rowSums(df1[cols]) == 0, cols] = NA

df1
#   RespondentID Popn1 Popn2 Popn3 Popn20 Funding1 Funding2 Funding3
# 1            1     1     0     0      0        1        0        1
# 2            2    NA    NA    NA     NA        0        0        1
# 3            3     1     1     0      1       NA       NA       NA
```

(Using akrun's kindly provided sample data as input)

We could then turn this into a function and loop over patterns:

```
# converts rows that sum to 0 to NA
# within columns that match a pattern
row_0_to_na = function(data, pattern) {
  cols = grepl(pattern, names(data))
  data[rowSums(data[cols]) == 0, cols] = NA
  return(data)
}

patterns = c("Popn", "Funding")
for(pat in patterns) {
  df1 = row_0_to_na(df1, pat)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - to understand the code: should it be pattern without an s (in the second part of the code? also If I use the first portion of the string(minus the number), it will find the columns that start with that string? so all of Popn, Funding, etc?

Comment: I used `pattern` inside the function, and `patterns` outside - perhaps a little inconsistent, but it doesn't matter outside the function what name is used inside the function.

Comment: It's using regex patterns - by default it will search for the pattern string (e.g., "Popn") anywhere in the column name, not just the the beginning. So a column named `"StartingPopn"` would also be picked up. If you read up a little on regex you can pass in any specific criteria. Add a `^` to the start of a pattern if you want to force it to occur at the start of the string, so `"^Popn"` will match strings only that start with "Popn".

Comment: That's great to know, luckily all my grouped variables have unique names so this solution worked well

Answer (score 1):

We can use `split.default` based on the column names of the data i.e. remove the digits in the column names with `gsub`, use that to split the dataset into subset of datasets in a `list`, then loop over the `list` with `lapply`, check for rows where there are all zeros (`i1`), assign those rows to `NA` (`x[i1,] <- NA`), return the data 'x', `cbind` them together

```
nm1 <- gsub("\\d+", "", names(df1)[-1])
lst1 <- unname(split.default(df1[-1], nm1))
out1 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(lst1, function(x) {
             i1 <- !rowSums(x != 0)
             x[i1,] <- NA
             x}))
```

and assign the output back to the original dataset

```
df1[names(out1)] <- out1
```

Or create a new dataset

```
df2 <- cbind(df1[1], out1)
```

-output

```
df2
#  RespondentID Funding1 Funding2 Funding3 Popn1 Popn2 Popn3 Popn20
#1            1        1        0        1     1     0     0      0
#2            2        0        0        1    NA    NA    NA     NA
#3            3       NA       NA       NA     1     1     0      1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(RespondentID = 1:3, Popn1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), Popn2 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L), Popn3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Popn20 = c(0L, 0L, 1L), Funding1 = c(1L, 
0L, 0L), Funding2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L),
Funding3 = c(1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```